# Using serial port connection in multiple functions?

Tags: c#, serial-port, port

I'm writing an application that is designed to read from a serial port then plot the data on a graph and save it to a log file. So far I'm working on the initial serial port setup and opening/closing.

There's a combo box to select the serial port to use, and a button to connect/disconnect. Is disconnecting from a serial port important or does windows do this automatically when the application is closed?

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace FieldProbe
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            cmbSerialPorts.DataSource = ports;
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnConnect.Text == "Connect")
            {
                btnConnect.Text = "Disconnect";

                if (cmbSerialPorts.SelectedIndex > -1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("You selected port '{0}'", cmbSerialPorts.SelectedItem));
                    Connect(cmbSerialPorts.SelectedItem.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select a port first");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                btnConnect.Text = "Connect";
                port.Close();
            }


        }

        private void Connect(string portName)
        {
            var port = new SerialPort(portName);
            if (!port.IsOpen)
            {
                port.BaudRate = 921600;
                port.DataBits = 8;
                port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                port.Parity = Parity.None;
                port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                port.Open();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

It's shamelessly taken from a couple of examples, I'm no expert coder. The line "port.close" does not work, it seems I cannot access "port" from any function other than "Connect". What is the best solution to accessing this port from other functions?

Comment: You need to learn about variable scope

Comment: In your button handler, you refer to the "active port" as `cmbSerialPorts.SelectedItem.ToString()` (the port name atleast). So why not do a `var port = new SerialPort(cmbSerialPorts.SelectedItem.ToString()); port.Close();`? You can also consider to save the `port` created in `Connect()` to an array or make `port` a `private SerialPort` in this class (i.e. change the scope of `port`).

Comment: Closing your application is closing your port automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise you read up on scope - but basically you are creating a port within the Connect method. This variable is local to this method and other methods (such as btnConnect_Click!) cannot see or access it. I would suggest you make the port variable a class member of MainForm (declaring it on the same level as your methods, MainForm_Load) - that way all class methods can access the variable:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    SerialPort _port;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        cmbSerialPorts.DataSource = ports;
    }

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnConnect.Text == "Connect")
        {
            btnConnect.Text = "Disconnect";

            if (cmbSerialPorts.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("You selected port '{0}'", cmbSerialPorts.SelectedItem));
                Connect(cmbSerialPorts.SelectedItem.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a port first");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            btnConnect.Text = "Connect";
            _port.Close();
        }

    }

    private void Connect(string portName)
    {
        _port = new SerialPort(portName);
        if (!_port.IsOpen)
        {
            _port.BaudRate = 921600;
            _port.DataBits = 8;
            _port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            _port.Parity = Parity.None;
            _port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            _port.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Providing that your code is correct and working, the only thing to do is to transform the variable port from local to the function to a field of the class. Here a possible solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace FieldProbe
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private SerialPort port;
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            cmbSerialPorts.DataSource = ports;
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnConnect.Text == "Connect")
            {
                btnConnect.Text = "Disconnect";

                if (cmbSerialPorts.SelectedIndex > -1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("You selected port '{0}'", cmbSerialPorts.SelectedItem));
                    Connect(cmbSerialPorts.SelectedItem.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select a port first");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                btnConnect.Text = "Connect";
                port.Close();
            }


        }

        private void Connect(string portName)
        {
            port = new SerialPort(portName);
            if (!port.IsOpen)
            {
                port.BaudRate = 921600;
                port.DataBits = 8;
                port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                port.Parity = Parity.None;
                port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                port.Open();
            }
        }
        private void OtherFunction()
        {
            if (port == null || !port.IsOpen)
                return;

            // HERE DO WHATEVER YOU WANT WITH port
        }
    }
}
```

Pay attention at the beginning of the class, where there is the field declaration, and at the end where there is a dummy function who uses the field.

Comment: `private var port = new SerialPort(portName);` won't compile since `portName` is an undeclared variable. Also `var` in that scope is not allowed, now it cannot deduce the type! (`var` only allowed in a funciton-local scope)

Comment: Yes, I was still moving the code when my phone rang and then I pushed the button...
I never use var... I just showed the principle.

Comment: I suggest, as the answer before mine, to use something to differentiate fields from variables. As the other user, I always use for fields a leading undescore.